# Getting table from Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, table

I have a map [Here](http://disignt.com/teddy/malawi/) based on leaflet JS and the layers are geojson. I would like to get a table at on another div when I click on each layers.

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You prepare an empty table with an id

```
<table id="properties"></table>
```

And you populate it with innerHTML property

```
for (var prop in properties) {
   if (properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        document.getElementById("properties").innerHTML = document.getElementById("properties").innerHTML + "<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>" + properties[prop] + "</td></tr>";
   } 
}
```

See on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/wo8cm8mt/) (it is done on mouseover, but you should be able to change it easily)